# PHP - Nested Shortcode To Array

Tags: php, regex, shortcode

I have following PHP function which converts shortcode such as

```
[column]
    [row]
        [column][/column]
    [/row]
[/column]
```

To nested array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag] => column
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                )

            [content] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [tag] => row
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [content] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [tag] => column
                                            [attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [content] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This works fine, if I have a single [column] as child, but if I have multiple column as child which is

```
[column]
    [row]
        [column][/column]
        [column][/column]
    [/row]
[/column]
```

Then it gives me incorrect nested array, which is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag] => column
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                )

            [content] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [tag] => row
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [content] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [tag] => column
                                            [attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [content] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tag] => column
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                )

            [content] => 
        )
```

)

Here is my PHP function

```
protected function shortCodeToArray($inputString)
{
    $itemArray = [];
    $openingTag = '/\[(\w+)(?:\s+([^\]]*))?\](.*?)(\[\/\1\]|$)/s';
    preg_match_all($openingTag, $inputString, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $tagName = $match[1];
        $paramString = isset($match[2]) ? $match[2] : '';
        $content = $match[3];
        $nestedShortcodes = $this->shortCodeToArray($content);
        $itemArray[] = [
            'tag' => $tagName,
            'attributes' => $this->parseShortcodeParameters($paramString),
            'content' => is_array($nestedShortcodes) && !empty($nestedShortcodes) ? $nestedShortcodes : $content,
        ];
    }
    return $itemArray;
}

protected function parseShortcodeParameters($paramString)
{
    $params = [];
    preg_match_all('/(\w+)\s*=\s*["\']([^"\']+)["\']/', $paramString, $matches);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
        $paramName = $matches[1][$i];
        $paramValue = $matches[2][$i];
        $params[$paramName] = $paramValue;
    }
    return $params;
}
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: I don't know the syntax of shortcode nor PHP, so I'm not writing an answer, but here's the gist: You are assuming that `(.*?)` balances itself, which it doesn't; [changing it to `(?:(?R)|\s)*?`](https://onlinephp.io/c/9b18be9c-4022-4a6d-a8a4-24e58abd4447) fixes the immediate problem (for this particular example where there are only tags and whitespace), but probably won't work in the long run (parse arbitrary, potentially incorrectly nested shortcode). The reason is similar to why parsing HTML with regex [gets dirty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491) really fast.

Comment: @Ibr perhaps your [mcve] should include more challenging input? Something that will populate `attributes` elements perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up doing it, thanks to @Markus Zeller and from another SO post which I am unable to find now.

```
// 1. Convert shortcode to XML like syntax
$xmlString = str_replace(['[', ']'], ['<', '>'], $shortcode);

// 2. Convert to xml using simple_xml_load_string
$xml = simplexml_load_string($html, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);

// 3. Convert to JSON
$json = json_encode($xml);

// 4. JSON to Array
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Although this worked, the `xml -> json -> array` created its own syntax and I wanted it in specific format with `has_children` and `children` keys, hence I am ended up using this function

```
protected function xmlToArray($xml) {
    $result = [];
    $result[] = [
        'tag' => $xml->getName(),
        'attributes' => [],
        'text' => '',
        'has_children' => count($xml->children()) > 0,
        'children' => [],
    ];
    foreach ($xml->attributes() as $key => $value) {
        $result[0]['attributes'][$key] = (string)$value;
    }
    $children = $xml->children();
    if (count($children) === 0) {
        $result[0]['text'] = (string)$xml;
        return $result;
    }
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $childArray = $this->xmlToArray($child);
        $result[0]['children'][] = $childArray[0];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Here is the result I am getting.

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag] => column
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                )

            [text] => 
            [has_children] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [tag] => row
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [text] => 
                            [has_children] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [tag] => column
                                            [attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [text] => 
                                            [has_children] => 
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [tag] => column
                                            [attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [text] => 
                                            [has_children] => 
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about the idea to convert it to HTML tags and use DOM Parser?

```
$codes = <<<'CODES'
[column]
    [row]
        [column][/column]
        [column][/column]
    [/row]
[/column]
CODES;
$html = str_replace(['[', ']'], ['<', '>'], $codes);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Outputting

```
<column>
    <row>
        <column></column>
        <column></column>
    </row>
</column>
```

Now you can traverse the DOMDocument like you want and even manipulate in a simple way.

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('row') as $row) {
    foreach($row->getElementsByTagName('column') as $column) {
        $column->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('test'));
        $column->setAttribute('class', 'test');
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

```
<column>
    <row>
        <column class="test">test</column>
        <column class="test">test</column>
    </row>
</column>
```

---

## Update

When having it as DOM Document you can traverse the whole tree and convert to an array.

See Demo: https://3v4l.org/h1eMR

```
function getTags($element, $tags = [])
{
    $tag = ['tagName' => $element->tagName];

    if ($element->hasAttributes()) {
        foreach ($element->attributes as $attribute) {
            $tag['attributes'][$attribute->name] = $attribute->value;
        }
    }

    if ('' !== ($nodeValue = trim($element->textContent)) && false === $element->hasChildNodes()) {
        $tag['nodeValue'] = $nodeValue;
    }

    if ($element->hasChildNodes()) {
        foreach ($element->childNodes as $childElement) {
            if ($childElement->nodeType !== XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
                continue;
            }
            $tag[] = getTags($childElement, $tags);
        }
    }
    $tags[] = $tag;

    return $tags;
}

$tags = getTags($dom->documentElement);
echo var_export($tags, true);
```

Comment: Didn't think about it, interesting. I'll play around with this a bit.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar I've updated the answer how you can traverse the DOM Tree and convert it to an array.

Comment: **I really like your idea of converting it to HTML tags**, as it will probably be **safer** than a complex regex like [the one I tried to set up here](https://regex101.com/r/WaPH9f/1). Regular expressions will get into trouble if the input is not correct. A parser should handle it in a better way and offers more flexibility. I just noticed that the DOM parser doesn't handle spaces in tags correctly. `[ tagname ] ... [ / tagname ]`  doesn't work. Quick fix: `preg_replace(['/\[\s*/', '/\s*\]/'], ['<', '>'], $codes);`. Also, **text nodes should be added to the content** (Ex: `CO[sub]2[/sub]`).

Comment: Correct, the text should be "sanitized" before moving to HTML parsing, then.

Comment: Thanks, based on your input I ended up converting the shortcode to xml like syntax and parse it using SimpleXml, which was much easier to handle.